# XCode Cocos2d EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, exc-bad-access

I followed a tutorial and made a little game with it.
The game works as follows, you control a special fish; enemy fishes spawns around and the goal is to eat the other fishes.

My problem is that I want to be able to eat any fish, in any order.
Right now I can only eat the enemy fish that was spawned last.

When I try eating a fish in the wrong order it crash with the EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=1 error.

I tried fixing it for hours but couldn't find it!

Here's my code :

```
@implementation HelloWorldLayer
NSMutableArray *_targets;
bool ScheduleVerification=NO;
NSMutableArray *ArraySides;

-(id) init
{
// always call "super" init
// Apple recommends to re-assign "self" with the "super's" return value
if( (self=[super init]) ) {
    CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
   player = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Fish1.png"
                                           rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, 15)];
    NSLog(@"//Init//");
    _targets=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  [self schedule:@selector(update:)];
    [self schedule:@selector(tracks:) interval:1];
    self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
    CCSprite *background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"UnderwaterBackground.png"];
    background.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
    CGSize BBox=[background boundingBox].size;
    [background setScaleX:(winSize.width)/BBox.width];
[background setScaleY:(winSize.height)/BBox.height];
    player.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
    [self addChild:background];
    [self addChild:player];
}
return self;
}
-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
NSLog(@"CB1");
UITouch *touch=[touches anyObject];
CGPoint location=[touch locationInView:[touch view]];
location=[[CCDirector sharedDirector]convertToGL:location];
if (location.x<player.position.x){[player setFlipX:YES];}
if (location.x>=player.position.x){[player setFlipX:NO];}

[player runAction:[CCSequence actions:
                [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.5 position:location],
                nil]];   
}
-(void)spriteMoveFinished:(id)sender {
   NSLog(@"CLEANUP");
CCSprite *sprite = (CCSprite *)sender;


    [_targets removeObject:sprite];
    [self removeChild:sprite cleanup:YES];

}
-(void)addTarget {
 NSLog(@"//addTarget//");
CCSprite *target = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"BadFish1.png"
                                       rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, 15)];

// Determine where to spawn the target along the Y axis
CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
int minY = target.contentSize.height/2;
int maxY = winSize.height - target.contentSize.height/2;
int rangeY = maxY - minY;
int actualY = (arc4random() % rangeY) + minY;
target.tag = 1;
[_targets addObject:target];

int ranSides=arc4random()%2;

int actualSide=winSize.width;
if (ranSides==0){actualSide=0;}

target.position = ccp(actualSide, actualY);
[self addChild:target];
NSLog(@"TARGET %@",target);


// Create the actions
id actionMove = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:15
                                    position:ccp(winSize.width, actualY)];
if (ranSides==1){actionMove = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:15
                                                  position:ccp(0, actualY)];
    [target setFlipX:YES];

}

id actionMoveDone = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self
                                         selector:@selector(spriteMoveFinished:)];
[target runAction:[CCSequence actions:actionMove, actionMoveDone, nil]];

}
-(void)gameLogic:(ccTime)dt {
 NSLog(@"CB2");
[self addTarget];
ScheduleVerification=NO;

}

-(void)tracks:(ccTime)dt {
NSLog(@"CB3");
int FishInterval=arc4random()%7+3;
// [self cleanup];

if (ScheduleVerification==NO){[self schedule:@selector(gameLogic:) interval:1 repeat:0 delay: FishInterval];}
ScheduleVerification=YES;
}

- (void)update:(ccTime)dt {

//  NSMutableArray *playerToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
//NSMutableArray *targetsToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    CGRect playerRect = CGRectMake(
                                       player.position.x - (player.contentSize.width/2),
                                       player.position.y - (player.contentSize.height/2),
                                       player.contentSize.width, 
                                       player.contentSize.height);

              for (CCSprite *target in _targets) {
        CGRect targetRect = CGRectMake(
                                       target.position.x - (target.contentSize.width/2),
                                       target.position.y - (target.contentSize.height/2),
                                       target.contentSize.width,
                                       target.contentSize.height);

        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(targetRect, playerRect)) {
        [_targets removeObject:target];[self removeChild:target cleanup:YES];
 //   [targetsToDelete addObject:target];
        }
        }
}
- (void) dealloc
{
NSLog(@"DEALLOC");
[_targets release];
_targets = nil;
[super dealloc];
}
```

and in the .h file :

```
@interface HelloWorldLayer : CCLayerColor
{
CCSprite *player;

}
```

What should I do to be able to eat fishes in any order? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are committing a heinous crime, removing elements from an array while you iterate through it.

Format your code a little better, and look at it:

```
for (CCSprite *target in _targets) {
    CGRect targetRect = CGRectMake(
        target.position.x - (target.contentSize.width/2),
        target.position.y - (target.contentSize.height/2),
        target.contentSize.width,
        target.contentSize.height);
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(targetRect, playerRect)) {
        [targetsToDelete addObject:target];
    }
    if (targetsToDelete.count > 0) {
        NSLog(@"Target Deleted");
        NSLog(@"targets %@",_targets);
        NSLog(@"target %@",target);
        [_targets removeObject:target];
        [self removeChild:target cleanup:YES];
    }
}
```

The fact that you have `targetsToDelete`, suggests to me that (either by forethought or the tutorial you followed), it was intended to do this properly. But a couple of things went wrong.

Consider this:

```
for (CCSprite *target in _targets) {
    CGRect targetRect = CGRectMake(
        target.position.x - (target.contentSize.width/2),
        target.position.y - (target.contentSize.height/2),
        target.contentSize.width,
        target.contentSize.height);
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(targetRect, playerRect)) {
        [targetsToDelete addObject:target];
    }
}

for(CCSprite* target in targetsToDelete) {
    NSLog(@"Target Deleted");
    NSLog(@"targets %@",_targets);
    NSLog(@"target %@",target);
    [_targets removeObject:target];
    [self removeChild:target cleanup:YES];
}

[targetsToDelete removeAllObjects];
```

You now run through the `_targets`, add each one to that you've eaten into `targetsToDelete`, and **after** you finish iterating through `_targets`, you then remove them indivudually.

Comment: No problem. The lesson to take away is, tidier code is much easier to debug :)

Answer (score 0):

Your loop to check for a hit looks very peculiar. Why are you adding items to targetsToDelete? I think the final release on targetsToDelete might be the issue. Simplify the loop like this and see what happens (not in front of a Mac at the mo) :-

```
- (void)update:(ccTime)dt {
//  NSMutableArray *playerToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *targetsToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    CGRect playerRect = CGRectMake(
                                       player.position.x - (player.contentSize.width/2),
                                       player.position.y - (player.contentSize.height/2),
                                       player.contentSize.width, 
                                       player.contentSize.height);

              for (CCSprite *target in _targets) {
        CGRect targetRect = CGRectMake(
                                       target.position.x - (target.contentSize.width/2),
                                       target.position.y - (target.contentSize.height/2),
                                       target.contentSize.width,
                                       target.contentSize.height);

        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(targetRect, playerRect)) {



                 //    [targetsToDelete addObject:target];
                    NSLog(@"Target Deleted");
                    NSLog(@"targets %@",_targets);
                    NSLog(@"target %@",target);

                   [_targets removeObject:target];[self removeChild:target cleanup:YES];

                }

}
```

Comment: Nope unfortunately it didn't change anything. It's cleaner but I still crash when I eat a fish that wasn't last spawned.

Comment: Post up the stack trace, what line is it crashing on?